# Web Navigation loads last

Tags: javascript, css, performance, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

This problem refers to this site: 
http://kittysitting.com.au/contact-us-for-cat-sitting-brisbane-northside/

The problem I'm experiencing is that the navigation menu visually shows last. Usually taking a few seconds after the rest of the page has loaded. The site is loading fine but this makes it appear slow.

**My debugging so far:**

1. Disabling Typekit fonts - makes no difference. Fonts load super quick but the whole menu still takes ages to visibly appear even when using 'sans-serif' font.
2. Disabling Wordpress Dynamic Menu - I tried inserting a purely static menu and it still won't appear for a few seconds after page load. Ruling out anything wrong with Wordpress/PHP.

My guess is it is a Javascript issue or CSS.

**My Question for Stack Overflow is:**

1. What is the best way to debug this issue. I'm familiar with Chrome developer tools, but I need to see what exactly is holding it up for the few seconds before the navigation appears.

**UPDATE:**
Found that a Javascript for responsive navigation is the cause. (If I disable the script it works fine). Have contacted js library owner on github to ask for further assistance as to why its doing it....

Comment: can you stick all your JS in the bottom of your files?

Comment: ...and problaby unrelated, but you have a lot of mysterious stuff in your html lang class.

Comment: With JS turned off, the menu loads instantly, so there's your culprit. Agree with boblet about scripts at the bottom. Worth trying as a first step.

Comment: Thanks Everyone - I've updated the post as I found it was a responsive navigation js file.